# Most efficient way to replace/add certain URL query string parameters? Minimize load time/redirects

Tags: javascript, string, url, parameters

We use three query strings that are pulled into form fields before a user submits. src, cst, and cid are the three parameters. cid and cst always need to be updated to the correct value. src will vary, but if none exists on the URL it should add a default one. I have this working, but think there has to be a much quicker, easier, faster way to do all of this.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var src = "Report";
var cid = "7013475893xfvg";
var cst = "Responded";
var vsrc = "src";
var vcid = "cid";
var vcst = "cst";
var srcstring = "&" + vsrc + "=" + src;
if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    searchParams.set(vcid, cid);
    searchParams.set(vcst, cst);
    var newRelativePathQuery = window.location.pathname + '?' + searchParams.toString();
    history.pushState(null, '', newRelativePathQuery);
}
if (!(window.location.href.indexOf(vsrc) > -1)) {
    window.location.search += srcstring;
}
</script>
```

First, the script adds or updates the cid and cst values to the correct ones defined in the variable. Then, the script determines whether "src" is present in the address bar. If it's not present, it adds the src parameter with a default value.

The goal is for this to be limited to at most one redirect, or history record. Ideally, the user will never see a reload, redirect take place and will not be present in their history. This works currently on Google Chrome desktop, but on Safari Mobile history records are created.

**Edit**: We discovered an issue with this code that also prevents form fields from gathering values if "%20" is any where in the URL. %20 gets converted to a "+" and breaks this process. How can we avoid this?